# Get the first value from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to get the first value ("source") of this json file

```
{
    "slides": [{
        "source": "images/Carousel-01.jpg",
        "title": "Slide 1 Title",
        "caption": "Slide 1 Description"
    }, {
        "source": "images/Carousel-02.jpg",
        "title": "Slide 2 Title",
        "caption": "Slide 2 Description"
    }]
}
```

i am trying get the value with angular using this code

```
<div ng-repeat="img in slides">
   <img ng-src="{{img.slides[0].source}}" />
</div>
```

but always show me the field empty i do not know well how to get only the first or the last one. I do not if this is possible, im trying to create a carousel.

Comment: Use {{ img[0].source }}, also if you only want to extract a single field of your json slides, you don't have to use ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only the first image then you don't need ng-repeat

Try like this

```
<img ng-src="{{slides[0].source}}" />
```

Comment: Yeah in that way works perfectly, but i want just the source of the first image, With {{img.source}} i have all the images.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-repeat flag means it loops through all the objects (denoted by the { } ) in the slides array

So when you call img.slides[0].source:

1. img is the current slide object.
2. You are then telling the loop to look for an another array called slides in the current slide object (referred to as img).
3. You are telling the loop to get the first item in that array [0]
4. You are telling the code to look for the source property in that item.

Step 2 and 3 are wrong for your data. There is not an array of slides inside of each slide.

You just need {{img.source}}